# Determine $\chi(S_n)$ and $\chi'(S_n)$, where $S_n$ is the Sierpinski graph of order $n$.

Tags: graph-theory

> Determine $\chi(S_n)$ and $\chi'(S_n)$, where $S_n$ is the Sierpinski graph of order $n$.  Prove this by induction for both $\chi(S_n)$ and $\chi'(S_n)$.

I know only about vertex and edge chromatic numbers and the basics of graph theory.  I haven't learned about unique coloring yet.

I found that if $n = 1$, then $\chi(S_n) = \chi'(S_n) = 3$.  Notice that $S_1 = K_3 = C_3$, which is 2-regular graph of vertices three.  Then, since each of the vertices is adjacent to each other, we can properly color the edges of $S_1$ with three colors and no fewer and also color the vertices of $S_1$ with three colors.

If $n = 2$, then $\chi'(S_n) = 4$.  Since $S_2$ contains three vertices of degree 4, we need four colors to color the edges of the even vertices.  We are done for this part.

The proof gets tricky in the inductive parts.

Assume $\chi(S_n) = 3$ for any integer $n$.  We need to show that $\chi(S_{n + 1}) = 3$.  By inductive assumption, since $S_{n + 1}$ contains three subgraphs $S_n$, we can properly color the vertices of $S_{n + 1}$ with three colors.

Assume $\chi'(S_n) = 4$ for $n \geq 2$.  We need to show that $\chi'(S_{n + 1}) = 4$.  By inductive assumption, we can properly color the edges of $S_{n + 1}$ with four colors.

For both inductive parts, I am not sure what to do next.

Any suggestions or comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way of thinking about $S_{n+1}$ is that it is 3 copies of $S_n$ cobbled together at the extreme vertices.

**Hint:** For the induction of $\chi (S_n)$, add the condition that the 3 extreme vertices have distinct colors from each other.
Then, apply transformations to $S_n$ to obtain $S_{n+1}$ which also satisfies the additional condition. Think of how you can get $S_2$ from $S_1$.

**Hint:** For the induction of $\chi ' (S_n)$, add the condition that the 3 extreme vertices (of degree 2) have edge colors of $\{1, 2\}, \{3, 4\}, \{3,4\}$.
Then, apply transformations to $S_n$ to obtain $S_{n+1}$ which also satisfies the additional condition. Think of how you can get $S_3$ from $S_2$.

Comment: Where does "vertices of degree 2" come from?  Doesn't $S_n$ have vertices of even degree and vertices of odd degree for $n \geq 2$?  Also, what do you mean by "extreme vertices"?

Comment: @NasuSama The topmost, leftmost and rightmost (assuming upward pointing triangle).